# Type Error:takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given when I initalize object

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to learn objected oriented programming in python and receiving a curious error where the code seems to think I'm passing 2 arguments into a function I'm only passing one method when I initialize it. Can anybody Help

```
class basicbot:
    #constructor
    def __init__(self, name, size, power, speed, health):
        self.name=name
        self.size=size
        self.power=power
        self.speed=speed
        self.health=health

    #setter method
    def set_stats(self, name, size, power, speed, health):
        self.__name=name
        self.__size=size
        self.__power=power
        self.__speed=speed
        self.__health=health

    #printing method
    def __str__(self):
        return "name is %s, size is %s, power is %s, speed is %s, health is %s" % (self.get_name(), self.get_size(), self.get_power(), self.get_speed(), self.get_health())

    #getter methods
    
    def get_name(self, name):
        return self.__name
    def get_size(self):
        return self.__size
    def get_power(self):
        return self.__power
    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed
    def get_health(self):
        return self.__health

    #encapsulation
    name=property(set_stats, get_name)
    size=property(set_stats, get_size)
    power=property(set_stats, get_power)
    speed=property(set_stats, get_speed)
    health=property(set_stats, get_health)

#test code to make sure basicbot works

bot1 = basicbot("basicbot", 2, 3, 4, 5)
print(bot1)

#print(box1.get_name)
'''

My call error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/redacted 1/Documents/basicbot.py", line 45, in <module>
    bot1 = basicbot("basicbot", 2, 3, 4, 5)
  File "/Users/redacted 1/Documents/basicbot.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.name=name
TypeError: get_name() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Is this all your code? Where did you implement your functions??

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Can you provide a call stack?

Answer (score 1):

Your get_name method is expecting an extra parameter: **name**

```
def get_name(self, name):
        return self.__name
```

Remove the **name** parameter from this function to fix the issue

The getter method for a property can only have *self* as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably caused by your `property` function, where you have defined it to only take 1 argument, but gave 2 when executing it.